# retrieving binded text from xaml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have my xaml code as :

```
<ListBox x:Name="SecondListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Name="toggle3" Header="{Binding name}" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,20,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="440" Content="{Binding descrip}" Checked="toggleSwitch1_Checked" Unchecked="toggleSwitch1_Unchecked" Tap="toggleSwitch1_Tap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PivotItem>
```

Now i want to retrieve toggleswitch(toggle 3)'s header text in c# code. How can that be done?

Comment: What about `toggle3.Header`?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a data binding like you did, it should automatically update the variable you bound it to, name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a proper collection to serve as the ItemsSource Binding
the xaml would write as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SecondListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsCollection}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Name="toggle3" Header="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,20,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="440" Content="{Binding descrip}" Checked="toggleSwitch1_Checked" Unchecked="toggleSwitch1_Unchecked" Tap="toggleSwitch1_Tap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

You'll have to provide a property named `ItemsCollection` of type `IEnumerable<TModel>` in your DataContext
where `TModel` class shouldcontain `Name` property

Answer (score 0):

This should put you on the right path to access elements inside of ItemTemplate.Probably that's what your looking for.

http://dotbay.blogspot.in/2009/09/accessing-controls-in-wpf-itemtemplate.html